# Mirador words highlighting

Tags: ocr, iiif, mirador

I am showing OCR-ed book pages in Mirador viewer. All words with coordinates are fetched from elasticsearch and search is across all books (meaning I can't use IIIF search api).

I need to highlight certain words in Mirador viewer.
I know that this is possible using annotations, but I need to use those annotations for something else (user comments), so I need another way for highlighting. Highlights should be displayed immediately, while annotations can be toggled.

Is there any solution with Mirador and IIIF presentation protocol or highlighting could be done on image server layer (currently I'm using IIPImage which doesn't support highlighting)?

Is there any other image server that supports highlighting and is it a good idea to do it this way?

Thanks!

Comment: Even if coordinates of your words are managed by elasticsearch for all books, can't you add an argument in the request to filter the results of elasticsearch in order to get only the ones of the current book?

Comment: The problem was in words highlighting but I solved it with Cantaloupe image server and Cantaloupe redactions feature. Thanks.